# Is a Surly front rack compatible with tubus mount for eyeless forks?

Tags: commuter, touring, rack, commuting-bike, touring-bikes

I am looking at [the Surly front rack](https://surlybikes.com/parts/cargo/front_rack) and was wondering if it's compatible with [this Tubus mount](https://tubus.com/product.php?xn=32).

If it's not I'll have to go for the Tara but I was keen on having a platform on my front rack. Any decent recommendations ?

Comment: What type of fork/bike do you have. In general the tubes LM-1 mounts should be compatible with the Surly front rack in question, but that does not mean it will work on your specific bike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rack and Tubus mounts will work together. You should double check that the Tubus mounts fit your particular fork. If you are looking for a porteur style rack (with the front platform), also consider the [Specialized Pizza Rack](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/pizza-rack/p/132712), the [Soma Fabrications Porteur Rack](https://www.biketiresdirect.com/product/soma-fabrications-porteur-front-rack?adl=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwrNjcBRA3EiwAIIOvqxvN8z5dk1SWeCJQwVx88qNU60AbEhhVorxrANsyGkrtwaf-rYyS7BoCInAQAvD_BwE) and the [Velo Orange Porteur Rack](https://velo-orange.com/products/vo-porteur-rack). The Velo Orange rack doesn't even require fork eyelets.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I ended up going with the trusted tara+tubus mounts and dismissing the platform requirement...